# Pandas: get the dataframe rows which value is matched with regexp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
username
NA
NA
NA
['Bob']
['']
['']
['Meril']
['Aston']
['Meril+Aston']
```

I need all the rows which has Bob, Meril and Aston or Meril+Aston or Bob+Aston....all combinations.

I tried

```
df.username.str.extract(r"\['Bob.*|['Meril.*|['Aston.*")
```

It not working

Comment: There are another strings? there are lists?

Comment: string only ...but look like list comming in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
subset = df[df.username.astype('str').str.contains('Bob|Meril|Aston').fillna(False)]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
          username
3          ['Bob']
6        ['Meril']
7        ['Aston']
8  ['Meril+Aston']
```